# SQL - How to use COUNT() with more than one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table that includes an COUNT() function that returns all the fields and counts them out. Now, I need to join another table and return both the number of rows that match and the rows that do no match. I am not exactly sure how I can use the GROUP BY and COUNT() function and get the results I need.

```
SELECT tb1.type, count(tb1.type) as total
FROM table1 tb1
GROUP BY tb1.type
```

That will return the totals for me:

RESULTS for TABLE1:

```
Type total
Egg   200
Cream 133
Milk  12
```

That's great. However, now I have another table...table 2 that has some records that match so doing that same query on that table will show something like:

RESULTS for TABLE2:

```
Type total
Egg   187
Cream 103
Milk  6
```

So, my results will need to look like this:

RESULTS for TABLE1:

```
Type total totalINTABLE2 totalNOTINTABLE2
Egg   200    187                13
Cream 133    103                30
Milk  12      6                 6
```

Not sure if joining is best here, or a UNION, or EXISTS. What's getting me confused is the group by.

Comment: Are you trying to find items that are in a category that are not in the other table or just looking at the number of differences. What if you have different items (by ID rather than category) in the two tables? That is table 1 has some IDs that are not in table 2 and table 2 has some IDs which are not in table 1.

Comment: basically the main table (table1) needs to see how many of the idtypes in table2 match the idtypes in table1. The number should and will be even. The first table has all information. i just need to count the second table to see how far off it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply `JOIN` both the resultset like

```
SELECT tb1.type, 
tb1.total,
tb2.totalINTABLE2, 
(tb1.total - tb2.totalINTABLE2) as totalNOTINTABLE2
FROM (
SELECT type, count(type) as total
FROM table1 
GROUP BY type) tb1 
JOIN (
SELECT type, count(type) as totalINTABLE2
FROM table2 
GROUP BY type) tb2 ON tb1.type = tb2.type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to calculate the total in each table then join them together:

```
;WITH
    cte1 as (
        SELECT tb1.type, count(tb1.type) as total
        FROM table1 tb1
        GROUP BY tb1.type
    ),
    cte2 as (
        SELECT tb2.type, count(tb2.type) as total
        FROM table2 tb2
        GROUP BY tb2.type
    )

SELECT    ISNULL(cte1.type, cte2.type) as type,
          cte1.total as TotalInTable1,
          cte2.total as TotalInTable2,
          ISNULL(cte1.total, 0) - ISNULL(cte2.total, 0) as TotalNotInTable2
FROM      cte1
FULL JOIN cte2 ON cte1.type = cte2.type
```